# Программное подключение к WiFi сети

Tags: java, android

Пишу прогу, которая должна подключать телефон к WiFi точке.

Рядом с телефоном стоит роутер Dlink сеть - без пароля.
Делал по данному гайду https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically
Телефон подключается к сети.
Сделал возможность вписывать свое название сети через EditText - так не работает.
В отладчике отрабатывает полностью, однако  wifiManager.disconnect();
                wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
                wifiManager.reconnect(); - делает данные действия, но к сети не подключается.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

public EditText nameNetworkText;
public EditText passwordText;
public EditText typeNetworkText;
String networkSSID = "DSL-2640U";
String networkPass = "12341234";
String nameNetwork;
String password;
String typeNetwork;
public static final String TAG = "Basic Network Demo";
// Whether there is a Wi-Fi connection.
private static boolean wifiConnected = false;
// Whether there is a mobile connection.
private static boolean mobileConnected = false;

// Reference to the fragment showing events, so we can clear it with a button
// as necessary.
private LogFragment mLogFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.network);

    nameNetworkText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameNetwork);

    passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

}

public void getAccess (View view) {

    nameNetworkText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameNetwork);
    nameNetwork = nameNetworkText.getText().toString();
    passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    password = passwordText.getText().toString();
    typeNetworkText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.networkType);
    typeNetwork = typeNetworkText.getText().toString();
    String open = "open";
    String wep = "wep";
    String wpa = "wpa";
    WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
 //   WifiConfiguration conf1 = new WifiConfiguration();
    conf.SSID = "\"" + nameNetwork + "\"";
//    conf1.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
    // conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ networkPass +"\"";

    if (typeNetwork.equals(open)) {

        conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
    }

    if (typeNetwork.equals(wep)) {
        conf.wepKeys[0] = "\"" + password + "\"";
        conf.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
        conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
        conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
    }

    if (typeNetwork.equals(wpa)) {
        conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ password +"\"";
    }

    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);

    List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
        if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + nameNetwork + "\"")) {
            wifiManager.disconnect();
            wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
            wifiManager.reconnect();

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: а он находит эту сеть в списке через цикл? заходит в `if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {`?

Comment: да, вы правы, в отладке List = null

Comment: Пройдя строчку wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);  Сеть получает статус Отключена.

Comment: а пермишены есть все, что надо?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>